# print all data in datagridview into reportviewer

Tags: c#, mysql

I use a datatable to display records in datagridview. Can I use the datatable to display the same record in reportviewer?

```
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM seminar_information";
        MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, 
        myConnection.connect);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adap.Fill(dt);

        this.dataSeminarInfo.DataSource = null;
        dataSeminarInfo.DataSource = dt;
        this.dataSeminarInfo.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Seminar Date";
        this.dataSeminarInfo.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Seminar Time";
        this.dataSeminarInfo.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Topic";
        this.dataSeminarInfo.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Venue";

        this.dataSeminarInfo.Columns[0].Width = 165;
        this.dataSeminarInfo.Columns[1].Width = 165;
        this.dataSeminarInfo.Columns[2].Width = 165;
        this.dataSeminarInfo.Columns[3].Width = 165;
```

Comment: you need to do something like this
`DataSet1 ds = GetData();
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();`

[display-data-datatbase-RDLC-report-csharp](http://www.simplylearnprogramming.com/display-data-datatbase-RDLC-report-csharp/52)